# XCTAssertTrue does not fail when testing iOS UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing

I am testing a calculator that was written by someone else. I am trying to use xcode 7 to test all the basic functionalities.

Here is the test I am currently running that will not fail. I have used the new recording functionality to get all the button taps. However, I am unsure how to assert the value I am getting back is correct.

```
- (void)testExample {
// Use recording to get started writing UI tests.

XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.buttons[@"6"] tap];
[app.buttons[@"+"] tap];
[app.buttons[@"3"] tap];
[app.buttons[@"="] tap];

//what the equation should return (9 in this case)
XCUIElement *display = app.staticTexts[@"199"];
XCTAssertTrue(display);

//what the equation should look like (6 + 3 in this case)
display = app.staticTexts[@"222+5553"];
XCTAssertTrue(display);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to check that the XCUIElement with that label `exists`:

```
XCTAssertTrue(display.exists)
```

Answer (score 0):

XCTAssertTrue does not test whether one value is equal to another, if that's what you're expecting.

XCTAssertTrue tests for any value other than 0 (nil). Your `display` is not nil; therefore it is true and the test passes.

Comment: So should I convert my display to an int and compare the values with XCTAssertEquals? I have tried to do this but I cannot figure out how to cast an XCUIElement as an int.

Comment: I haven't figured out what you think you're doing or want to do, and you have not explained it. So I have explained what you asked, namely, why your test always passes.